# PHP Где делать htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php

Делаю защиту на сайте.
Задумался над вопросом, где делать htmlspecialchars?

Мои варианты:

1) Сразу перед добавлением в базу

2) Перед тем как выводить в шаблон

3) В самом шаблоне

Какой вариант самый оптимальный? Есть ли еще?
Насколько я могу судить, большинство используют третий. Но в третьем приходится надеяться на верстальщика, а он может и ошибиться.

Answer (score 3):

Оптимальнее всего заготовить метод при открытии базы построчно перебирающий элементы массива попутно используя htmlspecialchars, но иногда лучше контролировать выхлоп по мере надобности(к примеру может возникнуть запара с JSON из-за кодировки и т.п.) Поэтому, как говориться, дорога ложка к обеду.

Answer (score 2):

простите, что? Вы знаете что делает эта функция? [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) Вы уверены, что вам эта функция нужна? к шаблонам она отношения не имеет. Она подойдет для вывода html сущностей на экран либо для записывания html тэгов в базу.

---

Вообщем, на данный момент я бы делал так:

- Верем то, что ввел пользователь;
- Вырезаем script, javasctipt;
- Обрабатываем функцией
     [strip_tags()](http://www.php.su/functions/?strip-tags),
     оставляя только разрешенные тэги;
- Обрабатываем функцией
     [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
     оставшееся;
- Запихиваем в базу.

Для вывода обратно, достаем, возвращаем теги наместо и выводим.

Comment: Ну так ведь шаблоны - это и есть вывод на экран, нет?

Comment: Не понял вас. Вопрос в том, где экранировать HTML для защиты от XSS. Непосредственно перед добавлением HTML в базу, когда достаем из базы или же когда выводим (в шаблоне).

Comment: а при доставании и выводе вам зачем это делать? то ли я идею не понимаю, толи вы не пробовали вывести данные после применения этой функции. после этой функции у вас на экране будет так как если бы вы открыли в редакторе html файл. эта функция отлично подойдет, если вы хотите вывести на экран пользователя этот html для редактирования.

Comment: Скорее всего вы не понимаете идею. Я программирую довольно давно и результат этой функции отлично знаю.
Когда данные в базу данных попадают от пользователей, они могут содержать HTML теги, в том числе вредоносный код, вроде какого-нибудь скрипта. При последующем выводе на экран надо все теги экранировать, чтобы браузер пользователей не выполнил вредоносный код. И тут вопрос, где это лучше сделать. Хранить теги в базе данных уже экранированными, либо перед тем как отправлять данные в шаблон, либо в самом шаблоне.

Comment: а, вот так понятнее :) Хотя тогда, раз вы знаете как работает функция, не понятно откуда 2 последних пункта появилось :) Видимо есть чтото еще.  
Тогда зависит от того какие данные вообще надо хранить в БД. Например для новостей я код хранил в БЖ со всеми тегами, предварительно вырезав из него все (регулярки в помощь), что связано с script, javascript, и после чего обработав его htmlentities.

Comment: Просто бытуют мнение, что хранить данные в базе лучше всего в первозданном виде, а заниматься экранированием тегов в самом конце - когда уже выводим на экран. Мне такая позиция не нравится, потому что шаблон делает верстальщик и может вообще не учесть такой проблемы.

Comment: Вообще не очень слышал про такое мнение, как минимум экранировать кавычки все же придется, но опять же, не понятна специфика вашего проекта/задания. Для чего это вообще? что может вводить пользватель (в плане того -- что в идеальном случае должен вводить пользователь)?
От этого и будет зависеть решение.  
А дизайнер/верстальщик вообще никогда неугадает что я захочу туда написать или я могу буквой ошибиться...   
Вообщем не все так однозначно.

Comment: Я не об экранировании кавычек. Это понятно и давно решено.
Я об экранировании HTML. А пользователь может ввести что угодно - вместо имени при регистрации введет <script>allert('hacked');</script> и вот дыра.

Comment: см. ответ. я дополнил.  
вообщем, напишите какие данные от пользователя вы хотите обрабатывать? :) А то приехали к тому, что у вас вообще разрешено вводить в поле для имени html... Воопервых такое вырезается еще на стадии ввода javascript'ом, по конкретному приведенному примеру: для имени пользвателя вообще должны быть запрещены спецсимволы. для начала можно навесить js, вторая проверка будет при сабмите данных на сервер. Используйте эту функцию там, где она действительно нужна, например при сохранениии текста где ДОЛЖНА быть html разметка, где ее не должно быть -- смело вырезайте.